# Does a Canadian citizen with an OCI (Overseas Citizen of India) require a visa to enter Singapore?

Tags: visas, singapore, canadian-citizens

I am a Canadian citizen and have an OCI. I am travelling from India to Singapore. Based on what I gathered [here](https://www.mfa.gov.sg/content/mfa/overseasmission/toronto/visitor_information/Visa_and_Entry_Requirements.html) and [here](http://visaservicescanada.ca/countries/singapore.php), I don't need a visa because Canadian citizens are free to enter and stay for up to 30 days.

Question:

> Will me being an OCI conflict in anyway while entering Singapore?

Comment: AFAIK OCI is merely a fancy name for visa-free access to people of Indian heritage so that they don't have to apply for Indian visa everytime they wish to visit. It is NOT a form of citizenship and is not a valid travel document (passport). So the question of it interfering with your regular passport does not arise.

Comment: @RedBaron according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overseas_Citizenship_of_India), "The UK government considers that, for purposes of the British Nationality Act 1981, 'OCI is considered to be citizenship of another State.'"  (This prevents people with certain classes of British nationality from registering as British citizens.)  So, for one purpose at least, it *is* a form of citizenship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a Canadian citizen, you do not need a visa to enter Singapore for a period of not more than 30 days. Having an OCI card gives you privileges while entering India only, and does not matter when you enter Singapore. The information you have in the links above is absolutely correct.